# Display Table from database to gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I am developing an online reservation and from the client's page I want his transactions to be viewed via gridview, but program returns an error and it says that "Additional information: Procedure or function 'JoinRoomSubPayment' expects parameter '@USERNAME', which was not supplied."

here is my code:

Sql:

```
SELECT USERNAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDAY, CONTACT_NUMBER, EMAIL_ADDRESS, HOME_ADDRESS FROM TBL_Client
WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME
```

ClassDisplaySummary.cs:

```
public DataSet _JoinRoomSubPayment(string user){
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("JoinRoomSubPayment", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds, "_JoinRoomSubPayment");
conn.Close();
return ds;}
```

ClientPage.aspx.cs:

```
user = Session["username"].ToString();
SummaryGView.DataSource = cd._JoinRoomSubPayment(user).Tables["_JoinRoomSubPayment"];
SummaryGView.DataBind();
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Your query statement seems correct but SP usage may not fit. Consider putting `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. And why using `_JoinRoomSubPayment` as source table in `da.Fill(ds, "_JoinRoomSubPayment")`?

Comment: I can't see the error, please explain to me what is the error? my SP don't fit, why? thanks

Comment: Use debug mode in VS project, explain which line of your code throws the error. I can tell that your SP assignment doesn't fit since `ExecuteNonQuery()` method called before defining `CommandType` into `SqlCommand` which doesn't make sense. Have you using `CREATE PROCEDURE JoinRoomSubPayment` to build stored procedure?

Comment: Your statement seems correct , this error may occur due to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); remove this line from your code and then try

Comment: @SukhvindraSingh my code worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: hi @Newbie10 plz accept below answe bcos in question list your question seeing unresolved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement seems correct this error may occur due to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   remove this line from your code and then try

```
public DataSet _JoinRoomSubPayment(string user){
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("JoinRoomSubPayment", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
// cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); remove this line from your code 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds, "_JoinRoomSubPayment");
conn.Close();
return ds;}
```